# How to check if all subnodes of TreeNode are expanded?

Tags: c#, treeview, treenode

Is there any easy way to check expand the state of TreeNode and its children?

```
bool IsAllNodesExpanded(TreeNode nodeToCheck)
{
  // Use nodeToCheck.isExpanded
  // Use something to check all childrens
  // return something
}
```

Comment: Only a tip, if you work with c#, use pascal case for methods. E.g.: `IsAllNodesExpanded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is specific to a particular WinForm component, but the solution I'm going to write you is more general. Therefore I'll explain my solution to you considering a general tree, but the code I'll provide you solves *your own* problem.

What you want to do is basically a [***tree traversal***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), which is the process of traversing all the children of a tree given it's root. Basically we need to check whether *all* the descendants (not the children) of a node. The difference between children and descendant is that children share the same parent (for instance A B C are children of X if and only if A B and C are directly connected to X), whereas descendants might be "children of children of children...of children (example: A is a descendant of X if, starting from X, there is a *path* on the tree that, starting from the node X, goes **down** to the node A).

In order to visit all the descendants of a tree we need a recursive function. In our case the function returns a boolean that tells us whether all the descendants of a particular starting node are expanded. 
There is a sample code that does exactly what you've asked for:

```
bool areAllNodesExpanded(TreeNode nodeToCheck){

    if(!nodeToCheck.IsExpanded)
        return false;
    foreach(TreeNode n in nodeToCheck.Nodes){
        if (n.Nodes.Count == 0)
            continue;
        if(!areAllNodesExpanded(n))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

LuxGiammi

EDIT: the code snippet above could not be compiled because of two errors I made:
1. it's IsExpanded and not isExpanded
2. For some reasons I do not want to investigate further, `var n` is of type object whereas it should be of type `TreeNode`.
Mistake corrected

Comment: You're right... I missed an uppecase character when I was writing... The most important thing is that the *explanation* of what I am doing is clear and that you do not "copy-and-paste" code as it is. That's a **very** dangerous thing to do!

Comment: After foreach should be `if(n.Nodes.Count>0)` otherwise at the final node it will detect that it is not expanded, because it has no childs and it can not be expanded

Comment: Mistake corrected. i'm very sorry, but I did not test out the code snippet. I just assumed that a leaf of the tree was expanded by definition (which is not :-D)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `TreeNode` you could introduce your own class which derives from `TreeNode`. This class could have a recursive method `IsAllNodesExpanded` like this: (untested)

```
public class MyTreeNode : TreeNode
{
  public bool IsAllNodesExpanded()
  {
    if (!IsExpanded)
    {
      return false;
    }

    bool allChildsExpanded = true;

    foreach (MyTreeNode child in Nodes.OfType<MyTreeNode>())
    {
      if (!child.IsAllNodesExpanded())
      {
        allChildsExpanded = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    return allChildsExpanded;
  }
}
```